# Is there any api to find out the room temparature intensity , light intensity etc

Tags: iphone

Thanks in advance.
   Is there any api in iphone to calculate room or surrounding temperature intensity , light intensity programatically.

is it possible to find light intensity using iphone camera programatically.And i found out this app http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/realthermo/id432583584?mt=8 . Here some light and temperature measured apps are there.

Comment: You cant calculate room or surrounding temperature ! It's impossible !

Answer (score 0):

No,
The iPhone does not contain a thermometer.
Also there is no public API for accessing the ambient light sensor.

Comment: Thanks for ur response. Is there any other way to find light and temperature intensity in iphone.

Comment: You could use a HiJack... http://www.eecs.umich.edu/~prabal/projects/hijack/  to supplement the lack of needed hardware...

Comment: is it possible to find light intensity using  iphone camera programatically.

Comment: @sandhya, not with any kind of accuracy or repeatability because of auto-exposure.

Comment: @sandhya, that app also uses external hardware you must buy to get the temperature reading.